# Rog strix geforce rtx 3050 8gb

Tags: gpu, nvidia-geforce, asus

I was planning to make a new pc for my sister and then see that there is a broken connector on my gpu
[image]

Comment: You're going to have to be clearer about what is broken, or post clearer images. I see nothing wrong, just some potentially unfitted components.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question was if it is normal to have a broken connector on your gpu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal - it's not broken.

I've managed to find a good-quality
[image](https://www.ldlc.com/en/product/PB00481852.html)
of the card.
At high-zoom it's a little blurry, but looks like yours:

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much i thought it was broken thank you❤️

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).